# Azure Data Factory error while fetching pipeline RunId

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory Pipeline throws error "Failed to convert the value in 'schema' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct" If I use the queries with Dynamic content -

SELECT @pipeline().RunId AS RunId

OR

SELECT '@{pipeline().RunId}' AS RunId

in a Lookup Activity. I need the Run Id GUID.

Answer (score 1):

Any time I have to do this, I simply create a new variable in the pipeline and use a SetVariable activity. Then, select the variable you want to assign and for the value "@pipeline().RunId".

[image: Set variable activity]

Then, to use the value simple use "@variables('PipeId')" where you need (replace PipeId with your own variable name).

I suggest reading this to get a better grasp of expressions and functions in data factory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

Hope this helped!!